# Can't delete this stack? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I create new stack from mainstack and after I want to delete mainstack.

I can't it.

Here my code:

```
create stack "newstack"
go to stack "newstack" 
delete stack "mainstack"
```

How do I do?

Thank you

Comment: Tried here and it works. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
local tStackID
put the long ID of this stack into tStackID
create stack "newstack"
go to stack "newstack" 
delete stack tStackID
```

That seems to work in a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are confusing the removal of a stack from memory, and the deletion of a file from the machine.

The first is indeed invoked as you wrote, using the "delete stack" command.

The second would require the use of the "delete file" command, appending the appropriate pathname.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the inability to delete the stack is probably the fact that a script of your main stack is still running. Try to send a message to the new stack. That way, no script in the old stack will be running when it is time to delete it.

```
on createNewStack
  local myStackID
  put the long ID of this stack into myStackID
  create stack "newstack"
  go to stack "newstack"
  send "deleteOldStack myStackID" to stack "newstack" in 0 secs
end createNewStack

on deleteOldStack theStackID
  delete stack theStackID
end deleteOldStack
```

Call `createNewStack` from a `mouseUp` handler for instance. Put the `createNewStack` in the same button, card or stack as the `mouseUp` handler (if you put `createNewStack` at stack level, you can put the `mouseUp` handler at button level, but they have to be in the same stack).

Put the `deleteOldStack` handler into the new stack at stack level. It will run when the script in the old stack finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that removes the stack is inside an object or sub-stack, I think it must give an error. So you can try something like creating a stack and putting a code to that stack that is the one that removes the mainstack. Example:

`on mouseUp
    local tStack
    put the long id of this stack into tStack
    create stack "NewStak"
    set the script of stack "NewStak" to "on deleteMainStack; delete" & tStack & "; end deleteMainStack"
    send "deleteMainStack" to stack "NewStak" in 0.1 sec
end mouseUp`

Please note that when creating a substack this is part of your mainstack. So if you delete the mainstack it deletes all its substack. The above code creates another mainstack and deletes the one I call it. One way to delete the minstack of a substack is to tell it to merge into its own mainstack and then to delete the previous one. Remaining the same only in memory and not in the disc, since the filename property is substack it as that of its mainstack.